# How to aggregate different columns with different functions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
df

ID size product   x    y 
A   1     abc    0.3   5
B   1     abc    0.8   7
C   1     abc    0.5   2
D   3     def    0.6   1
```

And I want to aggregate it x with mean and y with sum

so the code for aggregate both by sum is like this

`df1<-aggregate(list(x=df$x, y=df$y), by=list(df$size), FUN="sum")`

How can I change that code to have a dataset like this one:

```
df2

size     x     y 
 1      0.53   14
 3      0.6    1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get 14 as sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `summarise()` function from the `tidyverse` set of packages when dealing with data frames  of this nature. This allows you to summarise over a group with multiple different equations. I have demonstrated what I'd expect the solution to look like below with this solution.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(size) %>%
  summarise(
    x = mean(x),
    y = sum (y)
  )
```

A base r solution would require a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

One option is `collap` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
collap(slt(df, -ID, -product), ~ size, custom = list(fmean = 'x', fsum = 'y'))
#  size         x  y
#1    1 0.5333333 14
#2    3 0.6000000  1
```

NOTE: we could have a range of columns in the `list` i.e.

```
collap(slt(df, -ID, -product), ~ size, custom = list(fmean = 2:3))
#  size         x        y
#1    1 0.5333333 4.666667
#2    3 0.6000000 1.000000
```

Or using the `mtcars` data

```
collap(mtcars, ~ cyl, custom = list(fmean = c(1, 3:5),
          fsum = c(6, 7), fmedian = 8:9))
#       mpg cyl     disp        hp     drat     wt   qsec vs am
#1 26.66364   4 105.1364  82.63636 4.070909 25.143 210.51  1  1
#2 19.74286   6 183.3143 122.28571 3.585714 21.820 125.84  1  0
#3 15.10000   8 353.1000 209.21429 3.229286 55.989 234.81  0  0
```

The `return` can be a `list` or `long_dupl` or `long` or `wide`

```
collap(mtcars, ~ cyl, custom = list(fmean = c(1, 3:5), 
       fsum = c(6, 7), fmedian = 8:9), return = "list")
```

---

If we want to use multiple functions for different columns, an option is to loop with `Map` and `Reduce` by `merge`ing the `list` elements to a single summarised output

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'size'), 
  Map(function(u, v) aggregate(reformulate('size', response = v), df,
      FUN = match.fun(u)), c('mean', 'sum'), c('x', 'y')))
#  size         x  y
#1    1 0.5333333 14
#2    3 0.6000000  1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), size = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L), product = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def"), x = c(0.3, 0.8, 
0.5, 0.6), y = c(5L, 7L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But is there a way to do it with aggregate? I am very familiar with that command.

Comment: How can I avoid taking into account `NA`s? in aggregate one I just use `na.rm=T`

Comment: @JorgeParedes with `aggregate` you need `na.action = NULL` along with `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: @user63230 you don't have to specify as by default it is TRUE `fsum(x, g = NULL, w = NULL, TRA = NULL, na.rm = TRUE,
     use.g.names = TRUE, ...)`

Comment: @akrun sorry i just spotted that thank you!

Comment: @user63230 it's okay.  But your question is pertinent if somebody wants to change those to FALSE

Answer (score 1):

The function `aggregate_multiple_fun` in the `SSBtools` package is a wrapper to `aggregate` that allows multiple functions and functions of several variables.

In this case a possibility is

```
library(SSBtools)
aggregate_multiple_fun(df, by = df["size"], vars = c(mean = "x", sum = "y"))
```

Then, the output variable names will be  `x_mean` and `y_sum`. For the names to be `x` and `y`:

```
aggregate_multiple_fun(df, by = df["size"], 
                   vars = list(x = list(mean = "x"), 
                               y = list(sum = "y")))
```

To make use of the parameter `na.rm` to `mean` and `sum`, extra parameters must be set to `TRUE`:

```
aggregate_multiple_fun(df, by = df["size"], 
                   vars = c(mean = "x", sum = "y"), 
                   forward_dots = TRUE, 
                   dots2dots = TRUE, 
                   na.rm = TRUE)
```

Forwarding extra parameters can be a pitfall and therefore this is not done by default. The `forward_dots` parameter is required, and in the case of `mean`, `dots2dots` is also required.